# Using tf.custom_gradient to calculate a Taylor's series approximation

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am supposed to calculate the Taylor series approximation of the function `cos(x) + 1` using a TensorFlow custom gradient.

I wrote the following code:

```
def approx_cos_p1(x, n=7, dtype=tf.float32):
    """Return the approximation of cos(x) + 1 using a taylor/series expansion up to order 7"""

    result = tf.constant(2, dtype)

    for i in range(1, n//2+1):
        if i % 2 == 1:
            num=tf.math.pow(x, i*2)

            den=math.factorial(i*2)

            result=tf.math.subtract(result,tf.math.divide(num,den))

        else:
            num=tf.math.pow(x, i*2)
            

            den=math.factorial(i*2)

            result=tf.math.add(result,tf.math.divide(num,den))

    return result

@tf.custom_gradient
def approx_cos_p1_custom_grad(x):
  def backward(dy):
    return approx_cos_p1(x)
  return x, backward

x=tf.Variable(3.0,dtype=tf.float32)

with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as t:
  output=approx_cos_p1_custom_grad(x)

print(t.gradient(output,x))
```

But according to the Tensorflow documentation, tf.custom_gradients should be used as follows:

```
#Establish an identity operation, but clip during the gradient pass
@tf.custom_gradient
def clip_gradients(y):
  def backward(dy):
    return tf.clip_by_norm(dy, 0.5)
  return y, backward

v = tf.Variable(2.0)
with tf.GradientTape() as t:
  output = clip_gradients(v * v)
print(t.gradient(output, v))  # calls "backward", which clips 4 to 2
```

The `approx_cos_p1()` function works perfectly.

The problem here is that the `dy` parameter in the function `backward()` is not being passed in `approx_cos_p1()` which is not as per the Tensorflow documentation. But I get the desired output as `-3.15`.

When I pass `dy` in `approx_cos_p1()`, I get an undesired output `1.14`.

Is my implementation of the function correct?